# Unit tests not recognized in Xcode 4

Tags: unit-testing, xcode4

I have three unit test classes in my project. All of them belong to my unit tests target, all three derive from `SenTestCase`, and all have at least one method in the form `- (void) test___`. Only one of them shows up in the Scheme editor, however, and only that one executes with the Test command when my testing scheme is active.

I tried removing them from my test target and adding them back, and it didn't make a difference. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been some sort of bug in Xcode. I renamed the superclass of the two classes that weren't recognized from `SenTestCase` to `SenTestCaseRun`, which broke the build, and then changed them back. They then showed up in the Scheme Editor.